# Convert datatype in Google Earth Engine from double to integer

Tags: google-earth-engine, geography-data-type

How can I convert a variable to another data type using Google Earth Engine? For example I've created a NDVI image in double number (interval value -1.0 to +1.0). I want to save the image in byte (Unsigned8Bit or Byte) after running a formula like this: NDVI8bit = 128 + 125*NDVI (interval value 3 to 253) in order to save disk storage capacity without losing information.

Answer (score 3):

Probably you would like something like this:

```
// Calculate NDVI for a Landsat 5 image
var NDVI = image.normalizedDifference(['B4', 'B3']);
var scaledNDVI = NDVI.multiply(125).add(128);
print(scaledNDVI);

var toBytes = scaledNDVI.toByte();
print(toBytes);
Map.addLayer(toBytes, {min: 0, max: 255})
```

[Link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/ad7927e0f9029440c7d4d3d6c5865f54) to script with a random location and LS 5 image